# $TMP is shown incorrect in Eclipse, comma is Included into property filter

Tags: abap, abap-adt

My SAP Username is: schmelzer,t. (yeah with comma and point)

Adding a connection to Eclipse the Project Explorer shows me my local objects ($TMP) seperated with schmelzer and t. how can I fix this.

[image: project explorer]

Problem is that it wants to separate with the comma but it shouldn't,

[image: configuration]

[image: explorer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usernames with commas are currently not supported.

see https://answers.sap.com/questions/13286879/local-object-tmp-not-shown-correct-in-eclipse-incl.html?childToView=13302908#answer-13302908

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the latest version of ADT.

I tried to reproduce your issue on ABAP 750 and ADT 3.14 and this type of names is processed correctly.

[image]

Also I created a couple of objects and nothing. I don't see such freakey thing

[image]